# Copying a row to another table and adding some variable at the beginning in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tow tables in my database. The first one has some records and the second one has historic records.

When i want to modify a record, I need to put the current record in the historic table and adding the author, the modification date and a comment on the modification.

Here are the definitions of my tables

records (record_id, name, domain, etc...)
records_h (hist_id, author, comment, modification_date, record_id, name, domain, etc...)

I took a look at the W3C documentation and found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp). The examples doesn't show how to add values to this method and i haven't found how to it via google.

Here is what I have done but it's not working:

```
INSERT INTO record_h 
  (hist_id, USER_COMMENT, AUTHOR, MODIFICATION_DATE, record_id, name, domain, etc...) 
SELECT hist_id.nextval, 'test', 'toto', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 331898, * 
FROM record 
WHERE record_id=331898;
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: "*It's not working*" is not a valid error message in Oracle.

Comment: You could use an alias for the table record r, and use as r.* in the select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
      RECORD_H ( HIST_ID,
               USER_COMMENT,
               AUTHOR,
               MODIFICATION_DATE,
               RECORD_ID,
               NAME,
               DOMAIN )
    ( SELECT
           HIST_ID.NEXTVAL,
           'test',
           'toto',
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           331898
     FROM
           RECORD
     WHERE
           RECORD_ID = 331898 );
```

Dont use * in your select, name the columns. The select should be enclosed using ( )

Comment: Its not must to enclose the select query in ()

Comment: There is absolutely **no** requirement to enclose the `select` with parentheses.

Comment: I named every columns in the select and it's working now. Thanks!
PS: And yes the () are not mandatory as stated on the W3C page I linked in my question ;)